# Integration with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, visual-studio-cordova

Based on my research ADAL can not be used for authentication with Azure AD B2C; MSAL is the recommended library for integration with Azure AD B2C. What is your recommendation for integrating Cordova mobile application with Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know too much about Cordova, but you can use any OpenID Connect or SAML2 Provider with B2C. You do not need to use MSAL library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this github package. https://github.com/jospete/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova. We are using this in production and works perfectly fine. This has been extended from adal to use it with AD-B2C. It works fine with iphone and android.